# Kibana alert send notification on state change

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana

I have been working with adding Monitoring and Alerts into our Kibana app. We are using Kibana as part of the AWS ElasticSearch service, and it is using opendistro-alerting

I have been able to create my monitor, and a trigger, which is successfully firing.
I have also added some destinations and confirmed that it is sending the alert to SNS and to Slack when my threshold is breached.
However, I was hoping that it would also send an alert on state change, for example when I acknowledge the alert in Kibana, or more importantly, if the alert returns to an OK state.

So far I can't see a way to configure this, and the only solution I can come up with is effectively creating an inverse threshold check and link them both with a common alert code externally so I can flag the original error as OK. But this sounds horrible as it would mean having a list of alerts twice as long as it needs to be, and half of them always in a breached state at all times.

Answer (score 0):

[The below solution has not be replicated]

Did you try looking into alert status API?

https://opendistro.github.io/for-elasticsearch-docs/docs/alerting/api/#get-alerts

```
GET _opendistro/_alerting/monitors/alerts
```

The above query will help you get status for ongoing alerts. You can try setting up another alert on this data to validate your acknowledgement.

PS: Most of the opendistro-alerting documentation applies to AWS Elasticsearch alerting, since AWS ES uses the same plugin.

Comment: This is looking at the approach from the opposite end - building something that will constantly be checking back to get the current status. What I was looking for is whether there is an outgoing hook that Kibana would send out when the state changes. It already sends an alert when the trigger goes to alert, and it knows when it has been Acknowledged or Completed, so I assumed this would just hook into the same processes and send a message to all destinations, but it doesn't.